# scipy.signal: filtering variable-time dataset

Tags: python, scipy, filtering

I have a large dataset of the form `[t, y(t)]` to which I want to apply an IIR low-pass filter (first- or second-order Butterworth should suffice) using `scipy.signal` (in particular `scipy.filter.butter` and `scipy.filter.filtfilt`). The problem is that `t` is not regularly spaced, which appears to be a requirement for the functions in `scipy.signal`.

For any "missing" points, I know that my signal remains unchanged from its previous value (so given two consecutive points `t1` and `t2` in my `t`-data and a point `T` not in the data, such that `t1<T<t2`, the "real" function `Y(t)` which I'm sampling would take the value `Y(T)=Y(t1)`). `t` is integer-valued, so I could simply add the missing points, but this would cause the size of my dataset to grow by a factor ~10, which is problematic given that it's already very large.

So the question is, is there a (sufficiently simple and low-overhead) way to filter my dataset without inserting all "missing" points?

Answer (score 0):

You can efficiently "wrap" your data into a function.

If your data is in the form of a list of lists then you'll need to convert it into a `dict` and to create a sorted list of your `t` values. Then you can interpolate the missing values using the list bisection algorithm in the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module.

Here's some demo code written in Python 2, but it should be straight-forward to convert it to Python 3, if required.

```
from random import seed, sample
from bisect import bisect

#Create some fake data
seed(37)
data = dict((u, u/10.) for u in sample(xrange(50), 25))

keys = data.keys()
keys.sort()
print keys

def interp(t):
    i = bisect(keys, t) 
    k = keys[max(0, i-1)]
    return data[k]

for i in xrange(50):
    print i, interp(i)
```

**output**

```
[2, 4, 8, 10, 14, 15, 19, 21, 22, 23, 26, 27, 29, 30,
 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 42, 43, 44, 48]
0 0.2
1 0.2
2 0.2
3 0.2
4 0.4
5 0.4
6 0.4
7 0.4
8 0.8
9 0.8
10 1.0
11 1.0
12 1.0
13 1.0
14 1.4
15 1.5
16 1.5
17 1.5
18 1.5
19 1.9
20 1.9
21 2.1
22 2.2
23 2.3
24 2.3
25 2.3
26 2.6
27 2.7
28 2.7
29 2.9
30 3.0
31 3.0
32 3.2
33 3.3
34 3.4
35 3.5
36 3.5
37 3.7
38 3.8
39 3.9
40 3.9
41 3.9
42 4.2
43 4.3
44 4.4
45 4.4
46 4.4
47 4.4
48 4.8
49 4.8
```

(I manually wrapped the output of `keys` to make it easier to read without horizontal scrolling).

You'll get a *tiny* speedup by re-writing the body of the interpolation function in one line:

```
def interp(t):
    return data[keys[max(0, bisect(keys, t)-1)]]
```

It's much less readable, IMHO, but the speed difference *may* be worth it if the function gets called a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by PM 2Ring works, but assuming that your data are already ordered by `t`, it is less efficient than possible. It takes log-linear time and linear additional space. You can write a generator that produces a transformed dataset with regular sampling intervals in linear time and constant additional space:

```
# Assumes that dataset rows are lists as described in the question:
# [[t1, Y(t1)], [t2, Y(t2)], [t3, Y(t3)], ..., [tz, Y(tz)]]
# If this assumption is wrong, just extract t and Y(t) in another way.

# The generated range starts at t1 and ends directly after tz.
# Warning: will overgenerate points if the data are more densely sampled
# than the requested sampling interval.

def step_interpolate(dataset, interval):
    left = next(dataset)   # [t1, Y(t1)]
    right = next(dataset)  # [t2, Y(t2)]
    t_regular = left[0]
    while True:
        if left is right:          # same list object
            right = next(dataset)  # iteration stops when dataset stops
        if right[0] <= t_regular:
            left = right
        yield [t_regular, left[1]]
        t_regular += interval
```

Testing:

```
data = [[1, 10], [15, 2], [50, 100], [55, 17]]
for item in step_interpolate(iter(data), 10):
    print item[0], item[1]
```

Output:

```
1 10
11 10
21 2
31 2
41 2
51 100
61 17
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it looks like `scipy.filtfilt` doesn't accept generators, so I still have to build an array. I think at this point I should just take the plunge to see if that works without hitting the ol' OOM kill, because I fear anything else will turn into a true DIY solution where SciPy can't help me any more.

Comment: After some head-scratching, it looks like this generator fails if the points are more densely packed than `interval`. If you try e.g. `dataset=[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]]`, then `step_interpolate(dataset, 3)` will give `[[1, 1], [4, 2], [7, 3], [10, 4]]`. Not _too_ relevant to my case, but it's an important caveat.

Comment: Regarding the first point: you can wrap the call to `step_interpolate(iter(data), interval)` inside a call to whatever array datastructure you are using (`np.array` or something?). You lose the memory advantage, but keep the speed advantage. Regarding the second point: good call, I will add a comment about the packing density caveat. I can also fix that problem if you want.

Comment: I'm now building an array using `numpy.fromiter`, which works (unfortunately there does not appear to be a memory-mapped version of that). With a bit of luck I'll be able to avoid the OOM kill for each dataset if I write the filtered data to disk and memory-map it for further operations. There's no need to fix the packing caveat unless you particularly feel like it. :)